# My big images do not fit into my image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, slider

I have an image slider. It is 100% wide and it's height is 400px. I'd like my picture which are always bigger than the slider (f.e.: 2500*1250 etc...) to fit properly in my slider. How can I do that? with a jquery script dinamically?

My code:

```
#slider { 

    width: 100%; 
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

--My ID's for the images displayed in the slider.--

```
#first {

}

#second {

}

#third {

}
```

Comment: Consider instead to use them as background images with `background-size:cover`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way for `img` in slider :

```
  #first img,#second img,#third  img {
     position :relative;
     width:100%;
     height:auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you no need to write jquery for that change your css like this

```
 #first img {
     width:2500px;
     height:1250px;
     position :relative;
     overflow: hidden;
 }
```

use same as the other image ID, but I think it's better use one class for all, because in a slider need all images are same size

Comment: wrong...slider has height 400px, you css would overflow the image! :)

Comment: yes but I think he need image like that. yes it need add overflow hidden I forgot that  :D

Comment: `to fit properly in my slider`..how will you fit 1250 in 400? :)

Comment: Don't know but he ask he need images bigger than the slider I just use value by his example

Answer (score 0):

Neither work. I've seen somewhere a guy who posted a js for this but I could not find that thread that's why I posted.